# Python CSV create new HTML Table Column

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x

Hi I have a csv file in the form of

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4 col5
AA    BA     CA    DA   EA
AB    BB     CB    DB   EB
AC    BC     CC    DC   EC
AD    BD     CD    DD   ED
```

How do I get around to create a new csv file with a new column COLTAble
New csv will be in the format.
    **Col1 Col2 Coltable**
Where coltable uses col3,col4, and col5 and takes the form of

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="width:50%;">
        COL3
        </td>
        <td style="width:50%;">
        COL4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;">
        COL5
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I want a third column to contain html , with information from col3,Col4and col5.

Comment: What trouble are you having creating html and putting it into a csv file?

Comment: Its the other way round. Im trying to create an HTML column  by merging 3 columns into an HTML table. Hence I will still end up with a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  Does your final csv have a different html table string for every row?

Nonetheless, pandas is really useful for reading and writing files like this.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
>>> print df
     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 col5
0   AA   BA   CA   DA   EA
1   AB   BB   CB   DB   EB
2   AC   BC   CC   DC   EC
3   AD   BD   CD   DD   ED



>>> df['Coltable'] = df.apply(lambda row: row[2:].to_frame().to_html(), axis=1)
>>> df_new = df.iloc[:, [0, 1, -1]]
>>> print df_new
Col1 Col2                                           Coltable
0   AA   BA  <table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead...
1   AB   BB  <table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead...
2   AC   BC  <table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead...
3   AD   BD  <table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead...
    df_new.to_csv('temp_new.csv', index=False)


>>> df_new.to_csv('temp_new.csv', index=False)
```

Now temp_new.csv looks like

```
Col1,Col2,Coltable
AA,BA,"<table border=""1"" class=""dataframe"">
  <thead>
    <tr style=""text-align: right;"">
      <th></th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <td>CA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col4</th>
      <td>DA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>col5</th>
      <td>EA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"
AB,BB,"<table border=""1"" class=""dataframe"">
  <thead>
    <tr style=""text-align: right;"">
      <th></th>
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <td>CB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col4</th>
      <td>DB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>col5</th>
      <td>EB</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"
AC,BC,"<table border=""1"" class=""dataframe"">
  <thead>
    <tr style=""text-align: right;"">
      <th></th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <td>CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col4</th>
      <td>DC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>col5</th>
      <td>EC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"
AD,BD,"<table border=""1"" class=""dataframe"">
  <thead>
    <tr style=""text-align: right;"">
      <th></th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <td>CD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Col4</th>
      <td>DD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>col5</th>
      <td>ED</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>"
```

Comment: From your approach you did understand my question,  Will have a good read of Pandas then try out your suggestion approach. Thanks